# How to multiply the two nearby elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, sum, multiplication

I have a list like below:

```
a = [ 1, 2 , 3, 4, s, s+1]
```

I want to keep the first two elements and then multiply the rest two nearby elements.
The result would be like below:

```
b = [1, 2, 12, s**2 + s]
```

I know if I want the summation, I can use the code below:

```
b = [*a[:2], *map(sum, (a[i: i + 2] for i in range(2, len(a), 2)))]
print (b)
```

and I will get the result which is : `[1, 2, 7, 2*s + 1]`
However, I don't know how to get the multpilication result.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a customized multiplication function:

```
def mul(lst):
    s = 1
    for x in lst:
        s *= x
    return s

[*a[:2], *map(mul, (a[i: i + 2] for i in range(2, len(a), 2)))]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar approach, but instead using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) with [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html):

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import starmap

s= 5
a = [ 1, 2 , 3, 4, s, s+1] 

[*a[:2], *starmap(mul, (a[i: i + 2] for i in range(2, len(a), 2)))] 
# [1, 2, 12, 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also use `zip`:

```
a = list(range(1, 11))

b = a[:2] + [x*y  for x, y in zip(a[2::2], a[3::2])]
b
[1, 2, 12, 30, 56, 90]
```